# Determine real coordinates of an object in a video file

Tags: c#, opencv

i'm doing a project to determine the distance of a ship from camera through a video file.Only information i have is distance to horizon, is about 15 km from camera. I can track and detect the ship but how can i find the real distance to the ship

Comment: Do you have any code to show what you've tried so far? If not, the responses may be open-ended and people won't be able to help as much.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the focal length and sensor height of the camera you can try below relation as this  [discussion](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12434/how-do-i-calculate-the-distance-of-an-object-in-a-photo) suggest.

```
distance to object (mm) = focal length (mm) * real height of the object (mm) * image height (pixels)
                          ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
                          object height (pixels) * sensor height (mm)
```

And the other is especially  for distant object, here you can use the equation by THE RULE OF 57 some think like

```
Distance of object= (Size of object * 360)/(2 * 3.14 * Angular size in degree).
```

And you can see more information on these [link](http://www.cfa.harvard.edu/webscope/activities/pdfs/measureSize.PDF).

Hope these helpful...

Comment: thanks Haris ship is a distant object but i have no idea of size of object .can i use camera calibration in my problem?